# Is constant merging with Mercurial common practice? Something wrong with this workflow?

Tags: mercurial, merge

My company is switching to Mercurial, and we're coming from Subversion.

We're noticing that we're having to do a LOT of merging in our workflow. For instance, if I change a file, commit, pull, update, push, and then my co-worker changes a file, commits, pulls, and updates, he gets a "crosses branches" error and has to do an hg merge. We're having to do this pretty much every single time we want to push to our central repository.

Is something wrong with our workflow?? It seems wrong that in our history for a given file there are going to be a ton of history entries that say "Merging with [changeset id]" "Merging with [changset id]."

Is this just the way it is? Or are we doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this.  The vast majority of merges should be automatic.  You **did** create two heads when you both made changes stemming from the same revision and going in divergent directions - your changes might or might not conflict.

If you want to eliminate the "merge" changesets (which aren't actually a problem), you can change/pull/rebase/commit/push instead of change/commit/pull/merge/commit.  In other words, before committing your changes, rebase them to the new tip.

Comment: Boo for suggesting rebase without warning someone that it's a form of rewriting history and has potential dataloss that merge never does.  Mercurial workflows involve merges.

Comment: @Ry4an : Rebasing before a commit has ever become public is not rewriting history.  It's just taking a diff of your changes and applying them to the new tip instead of the place you originally made the modifications.  Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: There's no risk of invalidating remote caches, but it does use some on-disk data structures that are usually append-only and does inserts on them.  There's a reason it's disabled by default in mercurial -- history modifying commands are.  Ask in #mercurial if anyone has ever had rebase fail and leave their repo disconnected.  It's worth warning a guy.

Comment: @Ry4an : If the problem is with the Mercurial-internal structures you could do the rebase via `hg export; hg clone; hg import` instead of using the rebase extension.  That will never ever fail.

Comment: yeah that's a much more traditional Mercurial workflow.  I'm not saying no one should ever use rebase, but they should always be warned it's a little closer to playing with fire than the traditional tools are.  Mercurial's primary author is very big on the idea that Mercurial is entirely usable without enabling any extensions, and I agree.  Personally, I love a merge-y history -- it lets me think back to my CVS days and laugh heartily. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the merges are being executed without manual merge resolution, then I would say mercurial and your workflow are behaving as designed.

Comment: What do you mean by "with no human intervention?" Do you mean, no manual resolution of conflicts? Or do you mean, no having to go "hg merge; hg commit" to do the merge?

Comment: I meant "manual merge resolution" but Borealid's answer is more complete which is why I upvoted it. I've edited my answer to clarify, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is common as you really do need to get your repos in a consistent state. One thing that speeds it up is instead of

```
hg pull; hg update
```

use [fetch](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FetchExtension)

```
hg fetch
```

This will intelligently do a pull and than either an update or a merge. It comes with mercurial so it's basically a matter of editing your .hgrc to add a line like so:

```
[extensions]
hgext.fetch=
```

If the merge goes cleanly you won't even notice it happening. That was a big help in my workflow.